# How can I do less than, greater than in JSON Postgres fields?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

If I have some json:

```
id = 1, json = {'key':95}
id = 2, json = {'key':90}
id = 3, json = {'key':50}
```

Is there a way I can use Postgres fields to query for key greater than >= 90?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the operator `->>` [(Get JSON object field as text)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), e.g.

```
with my_table(id, json) as (
values
(1, '{"key":95}'::json),
(2, '{"key":90}'),
(3, '{"key":50}')
)

select *
from my_table
where (json->>'key')::int >= 90;

 id |    json    
----+------------
  1 | {"key":95}
  2 | {"key":90}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: aand what if "json" is an array of key objects like [{"key":95},{"key":9},{"key":13},{"key":1}] and you want to return an entity from my_table who has at least one of the key values bigger than 13 ? I am trying out a lot of stuff here and I don't really reach a result :(

Comment: Use `jsonb_array_elements(json)` to unnest json array elements, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c6d81d9e228fb4e66186c0d508c744d2

Answer (score 10):

If you use postgres version >= 9.3, then you can:

```
select * from t
where (json->>'key')::numeric >= 90
```