# Rails - Postgres - jsonb column query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb column named 'available_quantity'. which will have sample values

```
{ "100": 50, "1000":10 }
```

Now, I want to query all keys with values less than 50.

I tried this query,

```
Bundle.where('available_quantity @> ?', {'100': 5}.to_json)
```

But this one gives me all the Bundle with available_quantity containing {100: 5}.

How can I do that? Is that even possible?

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531689/how-can-i-do-less-than-greater-than-in-json-postgres-fields. I think your keys should have one name for this to work, but multiple values

Comment: @Joel_Blum, yes if I have a key, then its easy. But looking for a way to do it with the existing DB structure.

Comment: What do you mean with _"with the existing DB structure"_?

Comment: @SuganyaSelvarajan More of a postgres question than Rails, I don't see that it's possible though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `->>` operator:

```
Bundle.where("(available_quantity->>'100')::int < 50")
```

Comment: @sebastian_palma, this is wroking. But I want to get all rows with any key having value less than 50.

Comment: is it even possible to give multiple keys over here? Bundle.where("(available_quantity->>'100, 50')::int < 50") ???

Comment: I think you can but you'd have to add a `AND` or `OR` operator, `available_quantity->>'100, 50'` isn't valid unless you have the very same JSON key for that.

Comment: okay, I have updated my json to be stored as an array.  sample: available_quantity: [{"denomination"=>"1000", "quantity"=>19}, {"denomination"=>"5000", "quantity"=>20}] . Now my query would look like Bundle.where("(available_quantity->>'quantity')::int < 50") . But it returns empty relation.

Comment: This is a new and different error. Feel free to create a new question @SuganyaSelvarajan.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62065706/rails-postgres-jsonb-column-query check here