# Search jsonb fields in postgresql with Hasura

Tags: postgresql, hasura

Is it possible to do a greater than search across a jsonb field using hasura?

it looks to be possible in PostgreSQL itself, [How can I do less than, greater than in JSON Postgres fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531689/how-can-i-do-less-than-greater-than-in-json-postgres-fields)

in postgres I'm storing a table

asset

- name: string
- version: int
- metadata: jsonb

the metadata looks like this.

{'length': 5}

I am able to find `asset` that matches exactly using the `_contains`.

```
{
  asset(where:{metadata : {_contains : {length: 5}}}){
    name
    metadata
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to find `asset` with a length over 10.

I tried:

```
{
  asset(where:{metadata : {_gt : {length: 10}}}){
    name
    metadata
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A. Possibility to do on graphql level directly

[Hasura documentation: JSONB operators (_contains, _has_key, etc.)](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/queries/query-filters.html#jsonb-operators-contains-has-key-etc) mentions only 4 operators:

> The _contains, _contained_in, _has_key, _has_keys_any and _has_keys_all operators are used to filter based on JSONB columns.

So direct answer for your question: **No. It's not possible to do on graphql level in hasura.**

*(At least it's not possible yet. Who knows: maybe in future releases more operators will be implemented.
)*

## B. Using derived views

But there is another way, the one explained in https://hasura.io/blog/postgres-json-and-jsonb-type-support-on-graphql-41f586e47536/#derived-data

This recomendation is repeated in: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/6331

> We don't have operators like that for JSONB (might be solved by something like #5211) but you can use a view or computed field to flatten the text field from the JSONB column into a new column and then do a like on that.

Recipe is:

**1. Create a view**

```sql
CREATE VIEW assets -- note plural here. Name view accordingly to your style guide
AS
SELECT
      name, 
      version,
      metadata,
      (metadata->>'length')::int as meta_len  -- cast to other number type if needed
   FROM asset
```

**2. Register this view**

**3. Use it in graphql queries as usual table**

E.g.

```
query{
  assets(where: {meta_len: {_gt:10}}){
   name
   metadata
}
```

## C. Using SETOF-functions

**1. Create SETOF-function**

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_assets(min_length int DEFAULT 0)
RETURNS SETOF asset
LANGUAGE SQL
STABLE
AS $$
SELECT * FROM asset
WHERE
  (metadata->>'length')::int > min_length;
$$;
```

**2. Register in hasura**

**3. Use in queries**

```
query{
  get_assets(args: {min_length: 10}){
   name
   metadata
}
```

I think that was the last possible option.

It will not gives you full "schemaless freedom" that maybe you're looking but IDK know about other ways.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for your answer, sadly I don't know beforehand what the entries will be in metadata and what might be searched on. so for my use case, I can't construct a view beforehand.

Comment: @com48 We had the same problem an we would like to have a solution on graphql-level too. Right now it's just not exists in hasura. There is actually a third way that we use mainly: extending with functions but again it will not give you full "schemaless freedom" - consider yourself do you need such level of freedom?

Comment: I wanted to make a mention that Option C has some potential, you could provide 2 arguments (_key text, min_length int) and make a function that uses the _key property to dynamically select the field: (metadata->>_key)::int > min_length.  Additionally you could make a couple different helpers assets_min_length, assets_between, etc and provide them as root fields within Hasura.  I should probably write this out as an answer, but I am being a bit lazy today.